# How to line up adjacent nodes in tikz that share a border

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Here is how I'm drawing it currently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=8cm,align=center] (qw) at (0,0) {\texttt{rax}} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{63}}] (top) at (-4,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{31}}] (low32) at (0,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{15}}] (low16) at (2,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{7}}] (low8) at (3,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{0}}] (bot) at (4,0) {} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=4cm,align=center,xshift=2cm,yshift=-0.7cm] (dw) {\texttt{eax}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center,xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.4cm] (w) {\texttt{ax}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=1cm,align=center,xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-2.1cm] (hb) {\texttt{ah}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=1cm,align=center,xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-2.1cm] (lb) {\texttt{al}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: current image]

Everything is fine except for the final row, where the two rectangles appear to be overlapping. There should only be one line in between `ah` and `al`—exactly in the middle. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a dedicated package for such diagrams: https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: @PeterGrill sorry - fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `inner xsep=0pt`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner xsep=0pt]
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=8cm,align=center] (qw) at (0,0) {\texttt{rax}} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{63}}] (top) at (-4,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{31}}] (low32) at (0,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{15}}] (low16) at (2,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{7}}] (low8) at (3,0) {} ;
\node[label={\footnotesize{0}}] (bot) at (4,0) {} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=4cm,align=center,xshift=2cm,yshift=-0.7cm] (dw) {\texttt{eax}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center,xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.4cm] (w) {\texttt{ax}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=1cm,align=center,xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-2.1cm] (hb) {\texttt{ah}} ;
\node[draw,rectangle,text width=1cm,align=center,xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-2.1cm] (lb) {\texttt{al}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar results but with `bytefield` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,
    bitwidth=.015\linewidth,
    boxformatting={\centering\sffamily}]{64}
\bitheader[endianness=big]{0,7,15,31,63}\\
\wordbox{1}{rax}\\[3mm]
\bitbox[]{32}{}
\bitbox{32}{eax}\\[3mm]
\bitbox[]{48}{}
\bitbox{16}{ax}\\[3mm]
\bitbox[]{48}{}
\bitbox{8}{al}\bitbox{8}{ah}
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Except for reversal of low and high bytes, looks good! Only seems much more complicated. +1 though for the demo!

Comment: Actually, after rereading it, perhaps it isn’t so complicated. I’d just need to learn the package

Comment: I ended up using `bytefield` in my final draft.

Answer (score 2):

off-topic, for fun and exercises:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, align=center,minimum height=5mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\ttfamily},
   lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt, above=3mm}
                        ]
\node[box=8cm,right=of {(0,0)}] (qw) {rax};
\node[lbl] at (0,0) {63};
\node[lbl] at (4,0) {31};
\node[lbl] at (6,0) {15};
\node[lbl] at (7,0) {7} ;
\node[lbl] at (8,0) {0} ;
\node[box=4cm,below left=of qw.south east] (dw) {eax};
\node[box=2cm,below left=of dw.south east] (w)  {ax} ;
\node[box=1cm,below left=of w.south east]   (lb) {al} ;
\node[box=1cm,left=of hb]  (hb) {ah} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

result:

[image]

**addendum:**
one ore solution, using `chains` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 0mm,
    start chain= going below,
   box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, align=center,minimum height=5mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\ttfamily,
                 on chain,anchor=north west},
   lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt, above=3mm}
                        ]
\node[box=8cm,right=of {(0,0)}] (qw) {rax};
\node[lbl] at (0,0) {63};
\node[lbl] at (4,0) {31};
\node[lbl] at (6,0) {15};
\node[lbl] at (7,0) {7} ;
\node[lbl] at (8,0) {0} ;
\node[box=4cm] (dw) {eax};
\node[box=2cm] (w)  {ax} ;
\node[box=1cm] (lb) {al} ;
\node[box=1cm,left=of lb] {ah} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

the result is the same as before.

Comment: Except for low and high bytes being switched, looks good! +1

Comment: @Dan, thank yo for pointing this. now is corrected.